# Azure Blob Storage. Container Properties/Calculate Size says > 20000 items. but API only gives 5000 with NextMarker node empty

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

when i look at container properties of a blob storage container through the azure UI and click the calculate size button... it tells me > 20000 items (and i'm expecting > 20000 items).

But when i use the API to get a list of those items i only see 5000 with NextMarker node empty.

GET /mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list

I'm expecting to see a character string in NextMarker node that i use in subsequent GETs to 'page' through the container.

What am i missing?

tia

n

Comment: Do you have virtual folders in your container?

Comment: no. just files.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake. the NextMarker node IS being populated.... must have been looking at the wrong XML.

sorry to disturb.